# Call variables three columns at a time in for loop

Tags: r, loops

I have the following example dataset with Y column (can be ignored) and two variables X1 and X2 which are coded as dummy variables in three columns each

```
Y0 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
X1.0 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
X1.1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
X1.2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
X2.0 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
X2.1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
X2.2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

df <- data.frame(Y,X1.0,X1.1,X1.2,X2.0,X2.1,X2.2)
```

I am trying to apply a function to each variable. So before applying that function, I tried the following for loop to call each variable (which I expect to call column 2:4 followed by 5:7 in the second loop)

```
for (i in 1:2)
{
onevar <- df[,3i-1:3i+1]
##to insert/apply a function here and store the value for each variable 
}
```

but I got this error message

```
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'complex'
In addition: Warning message:
In `[.data.frame`(a0, , 0+3i - 1:(0+3i) + 1) :
imaginary parts discarded in coercion
```

Any ideas or suggestions are highly appreciated as I need to apply this to a bigger dataset with many variables.

Comment: Thank you very much @d.b this works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You index `df` inside the loop in the way that `R` thinks you are referring to [complex numbers](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/complex.html). If you want `R` to multiple two terms, you must explicitly multiply with `*`.

If you want `2:4` and then `5:7`, you could use

```
for (i in 1:2){
    inds <- (3*i-1) : (3*i+1) 
    # do your function here
}
```

Or a bit nicer in my opinion:

```
for(i in 0:1){
  inds <- (2:4) + 3*i
}
```